# Big O of Nested Loop (int j = 0; j < i; j++)

Tags: big-o

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2) {
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
     //statement
   }
}
Answer: O(N)
```

I know that the first loop for `for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)` results in `O(log N)`.

The second loop `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)` depends on `i` and will iterate first `i` times then `i / 2`, `i / 4`, ... times. (where `i` depends on `n`)

I don't know the Big O for the second loop, but I thought the answer would be `O(log N * something)` where `O(log N)` is the outer loop and `something` is the inner loop?

How do you get `O(N)`?

Comment: You might want to look at the [sum of 1 / (2n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_⋯) because that is what you are doing.

Comment: @Progman hmm, so the inner loop is `O(n)` and the outer loop is `O(log N)`?

Comment: Yes and no. The inner loop is `O(i)`, but `i` is changing from the outside. In combination with the outer loop the inner loop looks like `O(N / log N)`. Multiply that with the outer `O(log N)` and you get `O(N)`, the same as the given answer.

Comment: @Progman could you elaborate on how `i` = `n / log n`?

Comment: It's the average of steps of the inner loop, based on the outer loop and based on `n`. The first iteration is `n` steps, the last iteration is `1` step. With the help of [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_⋯](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_⋯) you get `O(n / log n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop has a complexity of `O(log n)`, because of the `i /= 2`. But the inner loop is a little bit more tricky.

The inner loop has a complexity of `O(i)`, but the `i` is changing for each iteration of the outer loop. In combination with the outer loop you get a complexity of `O(n / log n)`. You get this as follow:

The number of steps, the inner loop is doing, is similar to the sum of `1/(2n)`, as described on [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_⋯](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF). At first you are doing `n` steps, then only `n/2` steps, then `n/4` steps and so on until you do only `2` steps and then finally `1` step. This sums up together to the result of `2n`. In total you run the inner loop `log n` times (as defined by the outer loop). This means the inner loop runs *at average* `2n / log n` times. So you have a complexity of `O(n / log n)`.

With the outer loop of `O(log n)` and the inner loop of `O(n / log n)` you get `O(log n * n / log n)`, which can be simplified to `O(n)`.

Comment: thank you. the only part i'm confused about is why we have to find the average? in every iteration of the outer loop (which runs at `O(log N)`, the inner loop will run at `O(i)` where `i = 2n`. so why do we need to find the average big O of the inner loop?

Comment: @csguy `i` is not `2n`. Instead it depends on the actual iteration of the outer loop. At the beginning it is `n` and at the end it is `1`. So on average it's `2n / log n`, which is `O(n / log n)`. If it were `i=2n`, then you could say it is `O(n)` (which it isn't), and that would result in `O(n * log n)` (which it isn't).

Comment: do you take average whenever the iterations may vary depending on the outer loop? can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872524/big-o-of-nested-loop-int-j-0-j-i-i-j when you have time