# Big O of Nested Loop (int j = 0; j < i * i; ++j)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

**Question 1**

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < i * i ; j++){

  }
}
Answer: O(n^3)
```

At first glance, O(n^3) made sense to me, but I remember a previous problem I did:

**Question 2**

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2) {
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
     //statement
   }
}
Answer: O(n)
```

For Question 2, the outer loop is O(log n) and the inner loop is O(2n / log n) resulting in O(n). The inner loop is O(2n / log n) because - see explanation here: [Big O of Nested Loop (int j = 0; j < i; j++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571492/big-o-of-nested-loop-int-j-0-j-i-j)

---

Why we don't do Question 1 like Question 2 since in Question 1, `j` also depends on `i` which means we should really be taking the average of how many iterations will occur in the inner loop (as we do in Question 2).

My answer would be: O(n) for the outer loop and O(n^2 / n) for the inner loop which results in O(n^2) for Question 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is wrong. The code is `Θ(n³)`.

To see that note that the inner loop takes `i²` steps which is at most `n²` but for half of the outer loop iterations is at least `(n/2)² = n²/4`.

Therefore the number of total inner iterations is at most `n * n² = n³` but at least `n/2 * n²/4 = n³/8`.

---

Your consideration is wrong in that the inner loop takes on average proportional to `n²` many iterations, not `n² / n`.

Comment: sir, what's my wrong ==> ? https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csum%20_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5En%5C%3A%5Csum%20_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5E%7Bi%5E2%7D%5C%3A%3D%5Csum%20%5C%3A_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5En%5C%3Ai%5E4%5C%3A%3Dn%5E5

Comment: @snr The inner sum evaluates to `i^2`, not `i^4`. It is just counting the iterations from `0` to `i^2`.

Comment: oops, yes sorry.

Comment: @walnut when do we consider the average that the inner loop takes?

Comment: @csguy You can use the average if you want to. That is a correct approach. You just calculated the average in the wrong way. Since I don't know how you got it you might want to explain that so I can correct it. The difficult part is actually figuring out the average. One approach that usually works is to order the iterations by increasing runtime and to look at the maximal value (here `n^2`) and the value at a finite fraction of cases, e.g. here `(n/2)²` at half of the cases. That way you know that (up to a constant factor) the average lies between those two values.

Comment: @walnut oh I see what youre saying. I just divided n^2 by n because I thought that was how you get the average of the inner loop. since there are n total iterations in the outer loop (since that's how they did it in Q2)

Comment: @csguy That only works if the number in the numerator is the number of *total* iterations of the inner loop, i.e. `n³`. But the number of total iterations is exactly what we search for in the first place. So that is somewhat going in circles. And yes, forming the average that way and then multiplying it with the number of iterations in the outer loop is pointless also for Q2. If you calculated the average that way then you had already calculated the actual answer to the problem itself beforehand as numerator of the average. The difficult part is figuring out why it is `2n` in Q2.

Comment: @walnut can you explain what you mean here "but for half of the outer loop iterations is at least (n/2)²"

Comment: For all outer iterations with `i>=n/2`, the number of inner iterations is `(n/2)²` or more (because at `i=n/2` the number of iterations is `(n/2)²` and it only becomes larger for larger `i`).

Comment: @csguy Q2's answer is correct, and the method as you described is also correct. However it is unclear what your though process was to arrive at `2n / log n` as the number of average inner iterations. If you assumed that `log n` comes from the number of iterations in the outer loop, then where does `2n` come from?

Comment: @walnut I remember that it's from understanding that 1/2 + 1/4 +... etc = 1

Comment: @csguy ok, that is correct, but then that is already the full answer to Q2, no need to consider any average

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206494/discussion-between-csguy-and-walnut).

Answer (score 1):

What your inner `for` loop is doing, in combination with the outer `for` loop, is calculating the sum of `i^2`. If you write it out you are adding the following terms:

```
1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + ...
```

[The result of that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) is `(2n^3+3n^2+n)/6`. If you want to calculate the average of the number of iterations of the inner `for` loop, you divide it by `n` as this is the number of iterations of the outer `for` loop. So you get `(2n^2+3n+1)/6`, in terms of Big O notation this will be `O(n^2)`. And having that gives you... nothing. You have not gain any new information as you already knew the complexity of the inner `for` loop is `O(n^2)`. Having `O(n^2)` running `n` times gives you `O(n^3)` of total complexity, that you already knew...

So, you can calculate the *average* number of iterations of the inner `for` loop, but you will not gain any new information. There were no cuts in the number of iteration steps as there were in your previous question (the `i /= 2` stuff).

Comment: what are the benefits of taking average of the i/=2 problem if we dont need to?

Comment: @csguy In the previous question it was just one possible approach to solve the problem. In this question using the same approach to solve the problem does not give you more information or make it easier to solve. You already knew it's `O(n^2)` for the inner `for` loop. You can use the "average" approach, but it's not needed, specially when you already know the answer and understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
void fun(int n, int k) 
{ 
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
    { 
      int p = pow(i, k);  
      for (int j=1; j<=p; j++) 
      { 
          // Some O(1) work 
      } 
    } 
}
```

Time complexity of above function can be written as 1k + 2k + 3k + … n1k.

In your case k = 2

```
Sum = 12 + 22 + 32 + ... n12.
    = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
    = n3/3 + n2/2 + n/6
```